# Akka Durable State restore

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I have an existing Akka Typed application, and am considering adding in support for persistent actors, using the `Durable State` feature.  I am not currently using cluster sharding, but plan to implement that sometime in the future (after implementing Durable State).

I have read [the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.7.0/typed/durable-state/persistence.html) on how to implement Durable State to persist the actor's state, and that all makes sense. However, there does not appear to be any information in that document about how/when an actor's state gets recovered, and I'm not quite clear as to what I would need to do to recover persisted actors when the entire service is restarted.

My current architecture consists of an HTTP service (using AkkaHTTP), a "dispatcher" actor (which is the ActorSystem's guardian actor, and currently a singleton), and N number of "worker" actors, which are children of the dispatcher.  Both the dispatcher actor and the worker actors are stateful.

The dispatcher actor's state contains a map of requestId->ActorRef.  When a new job request comes in from the HTTP service, the dispatcher actor creates a worker actor, and stores its reference in the map.  Future requests for the same requestId (i.e. status and result queries) are forwarded by the dispatcher to the appropriate worker actor.

Currently, if the entire service is restarted, the dispatcher actor is recreated as a blank slate, with an empty worker map.  None of the worker actors exist anymore, and their status/results can no longer be retrieved.

What I want to accomplish when the service is restarted is that the dispatcher gets recreated with its last-persisted state.  All of the worker actors that were in the dispatcher's worker map should get restored with their last-persisted states as well.  I'm not sure how much of this is automatic, simply by refactoring my actors as persistent actors using Durable State, and what I need to do explicitly.

Questions:

1. Upon restart, if I create the dispatcher (guardian) actor with the same name, is that sufficient for Akka to know to restore its persisted state, or is there something more explicit that I need to do to tell it to do that?
2. Since persistent actors require the state to be serializable, will this work with the fact that the dispatcher's worker map references the workers by ActorRef?  Are those serializable, or do I need to switch it to referencing them by name?
3. If I leave the references to the worker actors as ActorRefs, and the service is restarted, will those ActorRefs (that were restored as part of the dispatcher's persisted state) continue to work, and will the worker actors' persisted states be automatically restored?  Or, again, do I need to do something explicit to tell it to revive those actors and restore their states.
4. Currently, since all of the worker actors are not persisted, I assume that their states are all held in memory.  Is that true?  I currently keep all workers around indefinitely so that the results of their work (which is part of their state) can be retrieved in the future. However, I'm worried about running out of memory on the server.  I'd like to have workers that are done with their work be able to be persisted to disk only, kind of "putting them to sleep", so that the results of their work can be retrieved in the future, without taking up memory, days or weeks later.  I'd like to have control over when an actor is "in memory", and when it's "on disk only".  Can this Durable State persistence serve as a mechanism for this?  If so, can I kill an actor, and then revive it on demand (and restore its state) when I need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The durable state is stored keyed by an `akka.persistence.typed.PersistenceId`.  There's no necessary relationship between the actor's name and its persistence ID.

`ActorRef`s are serializable (the included Jackson serializations (CBOR or JSON) do it out of the box; if using a custom serializer, you [will need to use the `ActorRefResolver`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/serialization.html#serializing-actorrefs)), though in the persistence case, this isn't necessarily that useful: there's no guarantee that the actor pointed to by the ref is still there (consider, for instance, if the JVM hosting that actor system has stopped between when the state was saved and when it was read back).

Non-persistent actors (assuming they're not themselves directly interacting with some persistent data store: there's nothing stopping you from having an actor that reads state on startup from somewhere else (possibly stashing incoming commands until that read completes) and writes state changes... that's basically all durable state is under the hood) keep all their state in memory, until they're stopped.  The mechanism of stopping an actor is typically called "passivation": in typed you typically have a `Passivate` command in the actor's protocol.  Bringing it back is then often called "rehydration".  Both event-sourced and durable-state persistence are very useful for implementing this.

Note that it's absolutely possible to run a single-node Akka Cluster and have sharding.  Sharding brings a notion of an "entity", which has a string name and is conceptually immortal/eternal (unlike an actor, which has a defined birth-to-death lifecycle).  Sharding then has a given entity be incarnated by at most one actor at any given time in a cluster (I'm ignoring the multiple-datacenter case: if multiple datacenters are in use, you're probably going to want event sourced persistence).  Once you have an `EntityRef` from sharding,  the `EntityRef` will refer to whatever the current incarnation is: if a message is sent to the `EntityRef` and there's no living incarnation, a new incarnation is spawned.  If the behavior for that `TypeKey` which was provided to sharding is a persistent behavior, then the persisted state will be recovered.  Sharding can also implement passivation directly (with a few out-of-the-box strategies supported).

You can implement similar functionality yourself (for situations where there aren't many children of the dispatcher, a simple map in the dispatcher and asks/watches will work).

[The Akka Platform Guide tutorial](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/akka-platform-guide/microservices-tutorial/index.html) works an example using cluster sharding and persistence (in this case, it's event sourced, but the durable state APIs are basically the same, especially if you ignore the CQRS bits).